# How do I delete Fedora 15 from Ubuntu 12? Fedora was installed first

Tags: uninstall

I installed Fedora 15 on my laptop and deleted XP (at least I think XP is deleted).  Then I installed Ubuntu as dual boot with Fedora 15.  Now I want to remove Fedora 15 and leave only Ubuntu (and XP if it is still available).

Can anyone help with the steps to uninstall Fedora?  Please give me simple steps to follow, I'm a nooby.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

**OS-Uninstaller** is a small graphical tool to perform a clean and quick uninstall of any operating system (Windows, Mac OS, Ubuntu, other Linux distribution..) that is installed on your computer.

#### Features

- It supports removing only selected OS boot list entries in the GRUB.

  [image]
- Or completely remove the GRUB and replace it with the original MBR (master boot record) that was there before installing Ubuntu.
- It also automatically reformats the partition of the OS that you just removed into NTFS (default) or ext4, depending on the OS that was there before.
- Change the GRUB menu’s display timeout.
- Backup the partition table and the boot sectors (just in case).
- It also lets you manually change the MBR and its installed location of hard disk and the partition it’s linking for booting. But for most users, you don't have to tweak any of these.

  [image]

#### 1st option: get a disk including OS-Uninstaller

1. Download [boot-repair-disk](https://sourceforge.net/p/boot-repair-cd) (rescue disk including the Boot-Repair tool).
2. Then burn the image on a CD, or create a [live USB](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/FromUSBStick) using a USB flash drive that is 1GB or larger.
3. Boot it.
4. A window (Boot-Repair) will appear, close it.
5. Then launch OS-Uninstaller from the bottom left menu.

#### 2nd option: install OS-Uninstaller in Ubuntu

1. Boot your computer from an Ubuntu live DVD or live USB.
2. Choose "Try Ubuntu".
3. Open the terminal (Ctrl+Alt+T) and run the following commands:

   ```
    sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair
    sudo sed 's/trusty/saucy/g' -i /etc/apt/sources.list.d/yannubuntu-boot-repair-trusty.list
    sudo apt-get update
    sudo apt-get install -y os-uninstaller
    os-uninstaller
   ```

   os-uninstaller is available from ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair for all currently supported versions of Ubuntu.

#### Using OS-Uninstaller

1. Launch OS-Uninstaller.
2. Choose the OS you want to remove and click the **OK** button.

<sub>**Source:** revised from [Ubuntu Documentation OS-Installer wiki](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/OS-Uninstaller)</sub>

Comment: Make sure that you include where you got the info and images.

Answer (score 1):

You should use [GParted](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/gparted/) to delete the partition(s) for Fedora.

If you're currently using the Fedora bootloader (if you installed Ubuntu afterwards, you're probably not), then you may need to [boot a live cd to re-install grub](http://howtoubuntu.org/how-to-repair-restore-reinstall-grub-2-with-a-ubuntu-live-cd#.UY-jBkBDshY) afterwards (and it's a good idea to keep one handy always anyway).