# how to remove other linux os and stay with ubuntu only

Tags: dual-boot, uninstall, fedora

I have latest ubuntu 15.4. I wanted to try fedora so I installed it afterwards and got dual boot. Now I want to remove fedora and stay with only ubuntu.

1. How do I completely remove fedora and retrieve the space I gave it ?
2. How do I remove grub ?

please write in details.
I saw [How do I delete Fedora 15 from Ubuntu 12? Fedora was installed first](https://askubuntu.com/questions/294381/how-do-i-delete-fedora-15-from-ubuntu-12-fedora-was-installed-first) but it has little details and I counldn't manage to do that.

---

***update***:
I tryed what kyodake suggested and still don't understand how to merge the 2 partitions. Bellow is the current status in my gparted: (I want to merge sda4 (deleted fedora) to sda1 (my ubuntu)). How do I mount it exactly ?
[image]

Comment: First restore Ubuntu's grub to MBR. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/Installing#Fixing_a_Broken_System Then you should be able to just use gparted from live installer to remove & resize partitions.

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

In a Ubuntu session, open a terminal,

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>

Run it:

```
sudo -i
apt-get update
apt-get install --reinstall grub-pc grub-pc-bin grub2-common grub-common
grub-mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg
grub-install --root-directory=/mnt /dev/sda
grub-install --recheck /dev/sda
fdisk -l
```

*By fdisk identify the Fedora partitions, are suppose /dev/sda7 and /dev/sda8, continue running:*

```
umount /dev/sda7
umount /dev/sda8
gparted
```

*In gparted, select the hard disk, delete Fedora partitions y and to create a new, file system ext4, You can mount wherever you want in /media, /mnt, /home/user/.*

Close gparted and run:

```
sudo update-grub
```

Comment: Should be accepted as the answer!

Comment: Wow! It could be this straight forward... I was racking my mind for no reason... Glad I stumbled upon this. Updating grub config file wasn't a good solution, had a figure it the hard way!.

Answer (score 0):

1. Put Ubuntu's GRUB in charge.
   From Ubuntu, run `sudo grub-install /dev/sdX`, ...whatever X is in your case. If there is only one HDD, it's usually /dev/sda. To figure out what X is for sure, run `lsblk`.
2. Unmount, and delete the partition with Fedora, using the preinstalled Disks utility.

Comment: please see my update