# Removing Ubuntu from a machine that also has Windows and 2 separate hard drives with each OS

Tags: dual-boot, windows, laptop, acer

I am after removing Ubuntu from my Acer Predator laptop. It has a 250gb SSD with windows on and a 1tb HDD with Ubuntu installed. I am after getting rid of Ubuntu as I want to sell the laptop. Is it just a case of wiping the HDD with Ubuntu on and just re-format the drive?

Seen some literature on using the Windows disk to perform a safe recovery of the Windows OS however, if they're on separate drives. Does it matter?

Thanks for any help :D

Comment: Depends upon how you set up the bootloader.  Can you boot Windows directly off the Windows disk (without using grub)?  If grub is involved, you should set up the Windows bootloader again, since some grub files are on the Ubuntu disk.

Comment: How would I be able to check? I used the windows boot for months before installing ubuntu

Comment: Use the EFI menu (some key like f12 at power on) to select the SDD.  If it boots Windows directly without grub, you are probably good.  If grub shows up, you need to "reinstall" the Windows bootloader (well in a UEFI machine, maybe just rename the /EFI/Boot/bootx64.efi from the backup file in that directory).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I delete Fedora 15 from Ubuntu 12? Fedora was installed first](https://askubuntu.com/questions/294381/how-do-i-delete-fedora-15-from-ubuntu-12-fedora-was-installed-first)

Comment: Make sure Windows is set as default or first in UEFI boot order. See also: Uninstall Ubuntu from menu, Really UEFI boot menu 
http://askubuntu.com/questions/63610/how-do-i-remove-ubuntu-in-the-bios-boot-menu-uefi &
https://askubuntu.com/questions/429610/uninstall-grub-and-use-windows-bootloader